# appending variable to end of file with sed

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I have dates on the last line in files like this:

```
20230220
```

and I want to add hours like this:

```
2023022000
```

The hours are continuously assigned to a variable `i` in a loop.

How to use `sed` inside the loop to append that variable to the end of files.

I tried with:

```
sed '$a|$i|>end>' file.txt
```

But couldn't append to file.

Comment: Why `sed` ... Since you're using a shell loop already, append it with `echo "$i" >> file.txt`

Comment: Yes i did it with echo but boss doesnt want like this ..

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `sed` like so:

```bash
sed '$a'"$i"'' file.txt
```

**Notice**: you need to break the single quotes `'` around your shell parameter/variable so that it is expanded to its value or otherwise, it will be treated as literal `$i`.

You might, however not need `sed` at all ... Since you're already using a shell loop, you can append it using shell redirection with the append operator `>>` like so:

```bash
echo "$i" >> file.txt
```

That will put the value from the expansion of `$i` on a new line after the last line of the file.

`sed`, however might be needed if you want to put that value on the same last line at the end next to what's already in that line ... e.g. if the file has an existing last line that already has `20230220` at its end and you want to add `00` right next to it so it becomes `2023022000`, then you can use:

```bash
sed '$s/$/'"$i"'/' file.txt
```

**Notice**: for `sed` to edit the files(*instead of only printing to terminal*), you need to set the `-i` flag like so:

```bash
sed -i '$a'"$i"'' file.txt
```

Comment: It gives right result but  variable still doesnt append to file

Comment: @CelaleddinKızılkaya Then it might be a problem in assigning your variable at first place ... You can assign current hour for example with command substitution e.g. `i=$(date "+%H")` ... Plus, don't forget to break the single quotes as shown in the answer around the variable to expand to its value.

Comment: I have a loop from 00 to 18 three by three i is assigned here

Comment: @CelaleddinKızılkaya Please add your loop code to your question if you want me to look at it.

Comment: Ok i added some part of my code

Comment: Ah @CelaleddinKızılkaya … :-) … I think I got you now LOL … In order to edit the file itself instead of just printing to terminal, you need to set the `-i` flag i.e. like so `sed -i '$a'"$i"'' file.txt` … Is that what you want? … I am on my phone now but I’ll fix your question formatting when I get hold of a PC in a little while.

Comment: Yes exactly it is thanks very much <3.

Comment: @CelaleddinKızılkaya You’re welcome … I rolled back your edit to your question as the added part is not relevant anymore.